# c# Regex replace bracket pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Hoping this would be an easy one for regex experts out there.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
blah blah blah
[Image "pasted.bmp-20160720140433"]
blah blah
[Image "pasted.bmp-20160720140458"]
blah blah
[Image "download"]
blah blah
blah blah [Image "download3"] [Image "download5"] blah blah
```

I wish to replace the [Image "pasted.bmp-20160720140433"] with base64 embedded images. The image placements always start with "[Image " and always end with "]" the enclosing bracket.

Is there an easy regex replace that can do the job?

edit:

Ultimately I would like the string to be html compliant like this:

```
blah blah blah
<img src='data:image/png;base64,data_which_I_get_from_using_the_file_name' />
blah blah blah
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to replace image name with image bytes?

Comment: @NikhilVartak That will match multiple tags on one line as one

Comment: Oh yes @BradleyMoorfield. That `.*` is a culprit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\[Image "([.\-\w]+)"\]` will match your pattern

A little explanation:

`\[Image "` matches the first part of your pattern. The `[` is escaped here as `[]`'s have special meaning in the Regex language
`[.\-\w]` is a list of characters - `.` matches a period, and `\-` a hyphen. `\w` matches any word character, which is `A-Z, a-z, or 0-9`
The `+` means to match as many times in a row as possible
The `()`'s around `[.\-\w]+` make it a capturing group, which means when a match is found, the image name will be made available.
Finally, `"\]` matches the end of your pattern.

Note that when using this in C# you will need to escape certain characters to get the right string such as `"\\[Image \"([.\\-\\w]+)\"]"` or using an @-quoted string like `@"\[Image ""([.\-\w]+)""\]"`

Also, in the future, there are websites that can help with generating Regular Expressions and breaking down how they work, try inputting the above into [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

---

Now, using `Regex.Replace` directly won't work, as I assume the base64 content will depend on the image name. In this case, you can use the `Match` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx)

An incomplete example might look like this:

```
string pattern = @"\[Image ""([.\-\w]+)""\]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string file = "...";

foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(file))
{
    // Modify file here
    // match.Index will have the position of a match
    // match.Value will have the capture, e.g. "download3"
}
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, thanks for the in-depth explanation. Just expanding on the question a bit what if I wanted to extract the image name inside the brackets? Thanks again

Comment: The parentheses `()` in a regex make it a *capturing group*. When a match is found with the above pattern, everything between the " 's will be in the `match.Value` property

Comment: string pattern = @"\[Image ""([.\-\w]+)""\]";